# convert a word to a list of chars

Tags: python

I can split a sentence into individual words like so:

```
string = 'This is a string, with words!'
string.split(" ")
['This', 'is', 'a', 'string,', 'with', 'words!']
```

But I don't know how to split a word into letters:

```
word = "word"
word.split("")
```

Throws me an error. Ideally I want it to return ['w','o','r','d'] thats why the split argument is "".

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can access individual elements of a string just like in a list - i.e. `word[0]` will give you `w`.

Comment: yeah it's a duplicate, sorry didin't find it earlier. i'm deleting it.

Answer (score 27):

```
>>> s = "foobar"
>>> list(s)
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python string is iterable. This means it supports special protocol.

```
>>> s = '123'
>>> i = iter(s)
>>> i
<iterator object at 0x00E82C50>
>>> i.next()
'1'
>>> i.next()
'2'
>>> i.next()
'3'
>>> i.next()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    i.next()
StopIteration
```

`list` constructor may build list of any iterable. It relies on this special method `next` and gets letter by letter from string until it encounters `StopIteration`.

So, the easiest way to make a list of letters from string is to feed it to `list` constructor:

```
>>> list(s)
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Upvoted because I learned about StopIteration here :)

Answer (score 4):

`list(word)`

you can pass it to `list`

```
>>> list('word')
['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']
```

Answer (score 3):

In python send it to

```
    list(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over each letter in a string like this:

```
>>> word = "word"
>>> for letter in word:
...     print letter;
...
w
o
r
d
>>>
```

Comment: sorry, but that is not 'python way'