# Python Regex: Symbol + in every letter in the same word

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python.
I want to make a regex that allos the following examples:

```
Day
Dday
Daay
Dayy
Ddaay
Ddayy
...
```

So, each letter of a word, one or more times.
How can I write it easily? Exist an expression that make it easy?
I have a lot of words.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: So you want a regex that matches "one or more letters"? Or something else? Can you give an example of something that your regex _shouldn't_ match?

Comment: Why don't you just split your word into an array of chars and then put it back together with `+` after each character? You'd end up with `d+a+y+`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418561/convert-a-word-to-a-list-of-chars

Comment: Couldn't you do `D+a+y+ \gi`?

Answer (score 1):

We can try using the following regex pattern:

```
^([A-Za-z])\1*([A-Za-z])\2*([A-Za-z])\3*$
```

This matches and captures a single letter, followed by any number of occurrences of this letter.  The `\1` you see in the above pattern is a *backreference* which represents the previous matched letter (and so on for `\2` and `\3`).

**Code:**

```
word = "DdddddAaaaYyyyy"
matchObj = re.match( r'^([A-Za-z])\1*([A-Za-z])\2*([A-Za-z])\3*$', word, re.M|re.I)

if matchObj:
    print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group()
    print "matchObj.group(1) : ", matchObj.group(1)
    print "matchObj.group(2) : ", matchObj.group(2)
    print "matchObj.group(3) : ", matchObj.group(3)
else:
    print "No match!!"
```

## Demo

Answer (score 1):

To match a character one or more times you can use the `+` [quantifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). To build the full pattern dynamically you would need to split the word to characters and add a `+` after each of them:

```
pattern = "".join(char + "+" for char in word)
```

Then just [match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) the pattern case insensitively.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> word = "Day"
>>> pattern = "".join(char + "+" for char in word)
>>> pattern
'D+a+y+'
>>> words = ["Dday", "Daay", "Dayy", "Ddaay", "Ddayy"]
>>> all(re.match(pattern, word, re.I) for word in words)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`/d+a+y+/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/Jgaf6L/1):

- `d+` Matches `d` one or more times.
- `a+` Matches `a` one or more times.
- `y+` Matches `y` one or more times.

Comment: Hi David, I think the OP only gave this data as an example to show the kind of allowed matches.

Answer (score 0):

As per my original comment, the below does exactly what I explain.

Since you want to be able to use this on many words, I think this is what you're looking for.

```
import re

word = "day"

regex = r"^"+("+".join(list(word)))+"+$"

test_str = ("Day\n"
    "Dday\n"
    "Daay\n"
    "Dayy\n"
    "Ddaay\n"
    "Ddayy")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

This works by converting the string into a list, then converting it back to string,  joining it on `+`, and appending the same. The resulting regex will be `^d+a+y+$`. Since the input you presented is separated by newline characters, I've added `re.MULTILINE`.