# How to split a string to a matrix of characters

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

Assume that we have this array in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
arr = pd.DataFrame(['aabbc','aabccca','aa'])
```

I want to split each row to columns of its character. The length of the rows may differ.
It is the output that I expect to have (3*7 matrix in this case):

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1 a   a   b   b   c   Na  Na
2 a   a   b   c   c   c   a
3 a   a   Na  Na  Na  Na  Na
```

The number of the rows of my matrix is 20000 and I prefer not to use `for loops`. The original data is protein sequences. 
I read [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-array-of-characters), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113655/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-split-a-word-into-a-list), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418561/convert-a-word-to-a-list-of-chars), etc, and they didn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
One simple way to do this is using a list comprehension.

```
pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in arr[0]])

   0  1     2     3     4     5     6
0  a  a     b     b     c  None  None
1  a  a     b     c     c     c     a
2  a  a  None  None  None  None  None
```

Alternatively, use `apply(list)` which does the same thing.

```
pd.DataFrame(arr[0].apply(list).tolist())

   0  1     2     3     4     5     6
0  a  a     b     b     c  None  None
1  a  a     b     c     c     c     a
2  a  a  None  None  None  None  None
```

---

**Option 2**
Alternative with `extractall` + `unstack`. You'll end up with a multi-index of columns. You can drop the first level of the result.

```
v = arr[0].str.extractall(r'(\w)').unstack()
v.columns = v.columns.droplevel(0)
```

```
v

match  0  1     2     3     4     5     6
0      a  a     b     b     c  None  None
1      a  a     b     c     c     c     a
2      a  a  None  None  None  None  None
```

---

**Option 3**
Manipulating `view` -

```
v = arr[0].values.astype(str)
pd.DataFrame(v.view('U1').reshape(v.shape[0], -1))

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  a  a  b  b  c      
1  a  a  b  c  c  c  a
2  a  a
```

This gives you empty strings (`''`) instead of `None`s in cells. Use `replace` if you want to add them back.